# Prove a composite function involving cantor set is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\cal K$ be the Cantor set. Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, &\mbox{ if }x  \in \mathcal K\\
0, &\mbox{ otherwise }\\
\end{cases}
$$

and let $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous.
Prove that $f \circ g = h$ is measurable.

I know that $f$ is a measurable function. Than I proceed by

$$h^{-1}([a, \infty])=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb R, &\text{ if $a \le 0$} \\
B, &\text{ if $0<a\le 1$} \\
\varnothing, &\text{ if $a>1$.}
\end{cases}
$$
where $B = \{x \mid g(x) ∈ K\}$.

I feel it very hard to show $B$ is measurable. I know $m(g(B)) = 0$ is. As it is subset of Cantor set which is measure zero. But than I cannot proceed. What should I do?

Comment: Is $f=\chi_K$ ?

Comment: yes $f$  is characterstic function of $K$

Comment: What is your definition of *measurable*?  Borel measurable?  Lebesgue measurable?  something else?  What do you mean by $h^{-1}(a)$?  Presumably, you mean the preimage of some set, but it is not clear which set you are considering.

Comment: I consider Lebesgue measurable. $h$ is measurable if $h^{-1}([a,b])$ is measurable, so i am taking advantage of this\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Lebesgue set $L$:$$h^{-1}(L)=\begin{cases}g^{-1}(\mathcal K) & \text{if $1\in L$ and $0\notin L$} \\ g^{-1}(\Bbb R)& \text{if $1\in L$ and $0\in L$} \\g^{-1}(\mathcal K^c)& \text{if $1\notin L$ and $0\in L$} \\ g^{-1}(\varnothing)& \text{if $1\notin L$ and $0\notin L$} \\\end{cases}$$
Since $\mathcal K$ is closed, $\mathcal K^c$ is open. The continuity of $g$ shows $g^{-1}(\mathcal K)$ is closed and $g^{-1}(\mathcal K^c)$ is open. The other two cases are trivial.

Comment: How can we deduce from $K^{c}$ is open to it is measurable. I have only learned that close sets are measurable and there are no other material mentioning that on the net

Comment: @RickyNg If $U$ is open, then $U^c$ is closed, hence $U^c \in \mathcal M$ (the sigma algebra of measurable sets). But $\mathcal M$ is closed under complements so $U=(U^c)^c \in \mathcal M$.

Answer (score 1):

If $B = \{x : g(x) \in K\}$, then $B = g^{-1}(K)$

$g$ is a continuous function, $K$ is a closed set, then $g^{-1}(K)$ is a closed set so is a measurable set